# How to insert an array into different rows?

Tags: php, html, laravel

I tried all the solutions that i found during my research but nothing seems to work for me. Here's an overview of what i'm trying to do. As an admin i control the activities of the customer. The customer is the one who makes requests and i as the admin approve that request.
Tables
Packages
id | customer_id | bearer_id | status
Package_products
id | package_id |product_id | qty

blade
In my blade i made a foreach to display the current products that are currently on the cart of a customer. This blade is already on the page of the currently selected customer.

```
<div class="panel-wrapper collapse in">
    <div class="panel-body">
        {!!Form::open(array('route'=>'storeProduct', 'id' => 'example-advanced-form', 'method' => 'post'))!!}
            <div class="table-wrap">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table id="datable_1" class="table table-hover display  pb-30" >
                        <table class="table">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Qty</th>
                                    <th class="column-spacer"></th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                                <input type="hidden" name="customerid" value="{{$customers->id}}">
                                    @foreach($customers->products as $product)
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><input type="hidden" name="productid[]" value="{{$product->id}}">{{$product->name}}</td>
                                                <td><input type="hidden" name="qty[]" value="{{$product->pivot->qty}}">{{$product->pivot->qty}}</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </table>
                                    <br>
                                </div>
                                @include('errors.list')
                                <fieldset>
                            <div class="row">
                            <center>{!!Form::submit('Process', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary'))!!}</center>
                        </div>  
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
            {!!Form::hidden('_token', csrf_token())!!}
            {!!Form::close()!!}
        </div>
    </div>
```

I used dd() and it shows the array of products. I can insert the requested data to the packages table with no problem, but when inserting the array of products to the package_products table it only inserts the very last row. I need to insert those products into different rows. What am i lacking?
controller

```
public function storeProduct(Request $request)
{
  try{
    $package = $this->package;
    $productid = $request['productid'];
    $qty = $request['qty'];
    $bearer = Bearer::status()->package()->first();
    $package->customer_id = $request['customerid'];
    $package->bearer_id = $bearer->id;
    $package->status = 'pending';
    $package->save();

    if ($package->save()){
      $id = $package->id;
      $packageproducts = [];

      $packageproducts = [
        'package_id'=>$id,
        'product_id'=>$productid,
        'qty'=>$qty];
        DB::table('package_products')->insert($packageproducts);
      }
      return redirect()->route('index')->with('message', 'Package Successfully Added');
    }
    catch(Exception $e){
      return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['Error']);
    }
  }
```

Comment: You are saving `$package->save()` twice

Comment: where are you assigning the values in  $packageproducts array, that you are inserting?

Comment: @AfshanShujat sorry about that i was still in the process of renaming my tables. I edited it $packageproducts. Akintunde007 oh i didn't know that i could still save it without that thank you but it still inserts 1 last row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution, what i was missing was putting a for loop inside my function so it gets the array i want and saves it into different rows in my database. Here's my answer

```
public function storeProduct(Request $request)
{
try{
$package = $this->package;
$productid = $request['productid'];
$qty = $request['qty'];
$bearer = Bearer::status()->package()->first();
$package->customer_id = $request['customerid'];
$package->bearer_id = $bearer->id;
$package->status = 'pending';

if ($package->save()){
  $id = $package->id;
  $packageproducts = [];
  for(i=0; < count($productid); $i++){
  $packageproducts[] = [
    'package_id'=>$id,
    'product_id'=>$productid[$i],
    'qty'=>$qty[$i],];
    }
    DB::table('package_products')->insert($packageproducts);
  }
  return redirect()->route('index')->with('message', 'Package Successfully Added');
}
catch(Exception $e){
  return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['Error']);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have set up the eloquent models correctly in relation between the package and the product model, it would be as simple as this.

```
$package = App\Models\Package::first();

$package->products()->attach($packageProducts);
```

Comment: I'm quite new to laravel, do i need to have a pivot table to execute that? I'm planning to use query builder for this function, i don't know how to use eloquent that well yet.

Comment: The documentation on that is fairly easy. And believe me, it makes your life much easier as the hard work is all handled behind the scenes by laravel. This is why we would use a framework after all. Don't be lazy and check this out ;)

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships

Comment: okay one question, do i really need to implement a pivot table if i have a manytomany relationship or is my table okay as it is?

Comment: For many to many you definitely need a pivot table. For one to many, your table is ok.

If one product can belong to many packages, and a package can have many products, then you should definitely have a pivot table.

Comment: i tried it, it returns an integrity constraint violation